# How to use wildcard with files which names start with '-'?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

There are some files which names start with '-', such as '-1.png', '-2.png'. I can't operate them with wildcard, because those names are regarded as options:

```
bash-3.2$ ls *.png
ls: illegal option -- .
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]
bash-3.2$ rm *.png
rm: illegal option -- 1
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linuxunix-move-file-starting-with-a-dash/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use

```
ls -- *.png
```

or

```sh
ls ./*.png
```

The double dash is a common option in GNU tools to signify the end of options: any subsequent words starting with dash is a plain argument.
`rm` works the same way.

Answer (score 4):

Use `--`:

```
ls -- *.png
```

It signals that what follows are not options.

> `--`
>       Delimit the option list.  Later arguments, if any, are treated as
>        operands even if they begin with `-`.  For example, `sort -- -r`
>        reads from the file named `-r`.